# Не работает z-index контейнера

Tags: css, css3, z-index

Я уже делала их сестринскими, эти div. Пробовала по разному, но родительский контейнер не перекрывает нижний.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="a "></div> 
   </div>



.container {
    background-color: beige;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
.a {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы элемент с position: relative что-то перекрывал, ему ещё надо задать смещение относительно своего положения в потоке (а z-index в данном случае вообще не нужен):

```css
.container {
    background-color: beige;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 30px;
}
.a {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="a "></div
```

Но это просто Вам для примера. Подозреваю, что у Вас какая-то другая задача стоит - сформулируйте её более внятно и покажите (хотя бы картинкой) какой результат Вам нужен.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @mtuspeh, если мой ответ помог Вам, примите его, поставив галочку

Comment: Тай пойдет? Сработало? Галочка поставилась? Просто у меня пока мало репутации, мои баллы не учитываются.

Comment: @mtuspeh, да, всё ок. добавил Вам не много репутации :)

Comment: Спасибо большое!